# Material Design HTML5 with JQuery PopUp that opens a page (.html)

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning guys,
I'm trying to do a material design html page with a jquery popup that opens a new html page.

I'm using a template directly from google, it is the article template. (just google "material design template", open first result and go at bottom to find it)(sorry about that but without 10 reputation i can't post more than 2 links).

For the popup i'm using ColorBox: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox
The jquery file i'm using is named "jquery.colorbox.js"

The problem is: material design page has something like an overlay that hides the popup when it appears.
Image example: [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0gh3.jpg)

This is the script i have used in the article page:

```
<script src="scripts/ajax_googleapis.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: "example.html"});
  }

  function countDown(){
    seconds--
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0){
      openColorBox();
      clearInterval(i);
    }
  }


  var seconds = 10,
      i = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
</script>
```

Any type of help is much appreciated!

Comment: @LaljiTadhani sorry, i'm pretty noob at this. Where need i to add it? to the css?

Answer (score 0):

set the position of the popup to fixed, and then add a z-index of 2000 and above.

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css what need i to change in the css?